# Remove whitespace from custom annotated fields

Tags: java, spring, reflection

In my application I have lots of fields where user can insert numeric values. Requirement would be that any leading, leading or inline whitespace must be removed after submission. I have total about 10 fields that need that kind of formation.

**Edit**: It's Spring MVC application. Data is inserted through the web. Number (telephone) fields are String type and following is valid if inserted, but should be stripped before making it to the converters and other validators: " +44 123456 55 ", "+4 4 1 2 3 4 " or anything that would contain whitespace.

I have looked into Aspects, but haven't had any luck modifying the values via reflection.

So far I've came up with custom annotation `@NumericValue` and have it on all the fields that need to be formatted. My current solution would be to pass in an object which contains these fields and remove them by looping through using the following method:

```
public static void formatNumericFields(Object object) {
        for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            for (Annotation annotation : field.getDeclaredAnnotations())
                if (annotation.annotationType().equals(NumericValue.class)) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    if (getField(field, object) != null)
                        setField(field, object, getField(field, object).toString().replace(" ", ""));
                }
    }
```

I would ask if there is any more practical way of doing what I am trying to achieve. I wouldn't want to do .replace(" ", "") on all fields separately. For now I would call that method in 3 different controllers passing in the form data that needs to be formatted. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the solution to your problem, but to remove whitespaces I suggest using `.replaceAll("\\s", "")`. This also removes tabs, enters, etc., instead of just spaces. Also, using reflection in your regular Java project is in almost all cases not recommended. I myself only use it in UnitTests to temporarily change Default values to test multiple cases.

Comment: does it use spring mvc?

Comment: Yes. Latest Spring and Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Don't you just need to create and register a custom PropertyEditor/Converter for the relevant fields? See section 7.4.2 onwards http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: That might be an option. I've used it for date conversions, didn't come in mind to work a way for number fields as well. Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just forbit whitespaces as soon as the user inputs them? You can do this by using a `PlainDocument-Filter` for your `JTextFields`:

```
PlainDocument doc = new PlainDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int off, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        // Remove all whitespaces:
        fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\s", ""), attr);
        // This below could be used instead to remove all non-digits (whitespaces, letters, etc.)
        //fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
    } 
    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int off, int len, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        // Remove all whitespaces:
        fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\s", ""), attr);
        // This below could be used instead to remove all non-digits (whitespaces, letters, etc.)
        //fb.insertString(off, str.replaceAll("\\D++", ""), attr);
    }
});

JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
textfield.setDocument(doc);
```

As mentioned in my comment to your question, I've also used `.replaceAll("\\s", "");` instead of `.replace(" ", "");`, so it not only removes spaces, but also tabs, enter, and such.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is using a fat client.

Comment: No sorry, it's Spring MVC application. Inputs are done through web.